# Bike not starting after filling it with petrol, but was completely empty before

Tags: motorcycle, starting, fuel-system

My bike is a Honda dream neo-110cc
It was completely empty before I refilled it with petrol. Now it's not starting. Someone told me that I needed to kick-start it.
What was happening? What can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I beleieve the Honda Dream Neo 110 has a carburetor, and possibly has a vacuum fuel tap.

If it is a vacuum fuel tap then the engine needs to be turning over before it will allow petrol through.

Does the fuel tap have a "Prime" position? If so that allows fuel to flow even when the engine is not turning over